# Different embeddings of an affine variety correspond to isomorphic coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

> **Definition 1.15** (Polynomial functions and coordinate rings). Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety. A **polynomial function** on $X$ is a map $X \to K$ that is of the form $x \mapsto f(x)$ for some $f \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. By Remark 1.14 (b) the ring of all polynomial functions on $X$ is just the quotient ring
>
> $$A(x) := k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \big / I(X).$$
>
> It is called the **coordinate ring** of the affine variety $X$.

If Y is embedded via the inclusion maps in n-affine space and some m-affine space as well then how can we show that the corresponding coordinate rings of Y are isomorphic as k-algebras?
The reason I ask this is that I have been told that the coordinate rings really capture the geometry of the affine variety.The embedding of an affine variety in a bigger space does not matter because you get an isomorphism as k-algebras of the corresponding coordinate rings.So in that sense being an affine variety is a geometrically intrinsic property.

The definition above can be found in Gathmann's notes page-10 Definition 1.15 here:
[Notes on Algebraic Geometry](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019.pdf)

Comment: A good solution to this question depends on your definition for the coordinate ring of a variety. Please add it in an [edit]. Separately, please see the [MathJax tutorial on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tips about formatting math here.

Comment: I have made the necessary edit and added the definition.Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If you're working out of Gathmann, this should be addressed later in his notes: for instance, corollary 4.8 does exactly what you want. There's a bit of material to be developed between the definition you quote and that result, though - keep reading!

Comment: Actually I have already studied till corollary 4.8 and that's how this question struck me. Of course I can take X = Y in corollary 4.8 but then as per that corollary morphisms between X and Y correspond to k-algebra homomorphisms between A(Y) and A(X). Now how do I prove that embedding of X in two different affine spaces via the respective inclusion maps results in isomorphic coordinate rings? Then by this corollary it would follow that the two X's are actually isomorphic as varieties. I hope I am making sense. If not,kindly let me know what is it that I am missing

Comment: In fact the statement that I made in the post comes from this video lecture
(at 50:30 time)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2svkFbfNOs&list=PLbMVogVj5nJSNj24jdPGivlJtxbxua2by&index=20

Comment: The standard way is to show that the coordinate ring coming from an embedding is the same as the global sections of the structure sheaf, and as far as I can tell (I mostly skimmed) this is what Gathmann does. But your problem seems to be less about that and more that you're not so sure about what definitions you're working with - if you can't declare that $X\cong X$, something is very wrong. My advice: start again from the beginning, writing down carefully the definitions and properties you are using. Good luck and good day!